# Printing a list of lists in OCaml

Tags: recursion, ocaml

So I am trying to print a list of lists that would look like this:

```
[0;0;0;0;0];
[0;0;0;0;0];
[0;0;1;0;0];
[0;0;0;0;0];
```

I can use as many functions as necessary, but only one function may use a print function. Here is what I have so far:

```
let rec rowToString(row) = 
    if (row == []) then []
    else string_of_int(List.hd row) :: ";" :: rowToString(List.tl row);;

let rec pp_my_image s =
    print_list(rowToString(List.hd s)) :: pp_my_image(List.tl s);;
```

I know this is wrong, but I can't figure out a way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way to do it:

```
let rec rowToString r =
  match r with
  | [] -> ""
  | h :: [] -> string_of_int h
  | h :: t -> string_of_int h ^ ";" ^ (rowToString t)

let rec imageToString i =
  match i with
  | [] -> ""
  | h :: t -> "[" ^ (rowToString h) ^ "];\n" ^ (imageToString t)

let pp_my_image s =
  print_string (imageToString s)
```

The `rowToString` function will create a string with the items in each inner list. Notice that case `h :: []` is separated so that a semicolon is not added after the last item.

The `imageToString` function will create a string for each inner list with a call to `rowToString`. It will surround the result of each string with brackets and add a semicolon and newline to the end.

`pp_my_image` will simply convert the image to a string and print the result.